# How can I handle a constraint on a terminal state variable while avoiding infeasibility during SDDP.jl training process?

Tags: julia, stochastic-dual-dynamic-programming, sddp

I want to solve a multi-stage optimization problem using SDDP.jl in which I am having hard time using constraints on state variables at the termination.

Comment: I'll also gently remind you that the JuMP forum https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13 or opening an issue at SDDP.jl https://github.com/odow/SDDP.jl/issues might be a better place for these questions. or.stackexchange is a very broad forum, and these are quite niche questions. (You can see other SDDP.jl-related questions on the JuMP forum at https://discourse.julialang.org/search?q=sddp)

Comment: thats great, I will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a hard constraint to the terminal state variable. The model must have relatively complete recourse, so there must be a feasible solution for any incoming value of the state variable in the last stage.

You can instead add a soft constraint that penalizes the violation in the objective.

Comment: but i am using terminal constraint as an ethical constraint, it is essential to my research objective, can i use some other mechanism such as duality handlers...

Comment: No. There are no alternatives or workarounds. You must use a penalized soft-constraint.

Comment: Right, that's fine, thanks

Comment: Then, if I can not use hard constraint on terminal state variable, will it be the best approach to use hyperparameter optimization over the weight of the corresponding soft constraint such that the hyperparameter optimization will minimize the sum of real objective (in our original multi-stage optimization) and the term which is zero if the state variable is less then a threshold and some large number if that state variable is greater then a threshold.

Comment: Yes, you will likely need to tune the weight parameter by trying out different values to see what works.

Comment: Ok, got it, I have implemented this